# I'm getting 'undefined' as an output when accessing the transactions in userSchema (NodeJs & MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I expect the output as, it should `console.log()` the transactions onto my command prompt. It is only printing all the objects of `userSchema` accept transactions. It is printing "undefined"

```
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Running on port 3000
Connection established
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
 Running on port 3000
Connection established
5c4b294efb654f1770522264
{ _id: 5c4b294efb654f1770522264,
  email: 'dev@dev.com',
  username: 'username',
  password:
   'MY_SECRET_PASSWORD',
  privateKey:'MY_PRIVATE_KEY',
  __v: 0 }
undefined
POST /api/getTransactions 200 264.266 ms - -
```

**This is the POST route**

```
router.post('/getTransactions', function (req, res) {
    userId = req.body._id
    console.log(userId)
    //console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    User.findOne({ _id: userId }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)

        if (user) {
            console.log(user.transactions)
            res.send(user.transactions)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }

    })
})
```

**This is the user schema**

```
var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
       time: {
           type: String
    },
    date : {
        type: String
    },
    transactionType : {
        type: String
    },
    email : {
        type: String
    },
    amount: {
        type: String
    },
    txHash:{
        type: String
    }
})

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    ethAddress: {
        type: String
    },
    privateKey: {
        type: String
    },
    transactions: TransactionSchema,
})
```

Comment: Have you tried querying the underlying collection in mongo shell i.e. `db.users.findOne({ "_id": ObjectId("5c4b294efb654f1770522264") })` and check if the returned document indeed has the `ransactions` field?

Comment: I believe believe you are trying to make a relationship between UserSchema and TransactionSchema, so that when you select a user all his transactions are listed?

Comment: @elraphty yes correct. i don't know what is resisting it. But when i `console.log(user)` it actually returns the data accept the transactions

Comment: ok then you have to create a relationship between two Models i will paste and example as an answer

Comment: @devbeans is it working now?

Comment: @elraphty no buddy..  :(

Comment: @devbeans please post your models code, paste it with the schema, because if u followed the relationship   example I answered it should work except the error is from your model

Comment: @elraphty https://pastebin.com/q3VPdrF5 visit this url, this contains the whole schema

Comment: @devbeans can i update the file you made a very big mistake you defined a transaction schema without a transactions Model

Comment: @elraphty of course, of course, please and share the url of it here

Comment: @elraphty but the "transaction" data is saving successfully in the DB

Comment: @devbeans for real thats kind of strange to me, write a query to fetch all Transactions independently from using the users model and see if it works

Comment: @devbeans check this out [Link](https://pastebin.com/3JKe7stL)

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case, but with the few details you provided it seems you're not storing the transactions.
When transaction occurs, you have to push the transaction from where it's made (secure it first) into the transactions field (which doesn't seems to be an array in your code).

So, as far as I understand your problem and with the code you provided I would say that you should :

- Make your transactions field an array of `TransactionSchema`
- Push you're transaction to this array (in mongoDB see [MongoDB Push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/))

After that, when you get your `user` it should now include all the transactions made by this user.

Comment: i have done that "the push operation" . My DB actually has that transaction array with some data also but when you query that it returns `undefined`

Comment: Can you show us you mongoDB document ? (from mongoDB directly)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pPjR97VN  can't paste here because it is too long.. please visit that url .it is there

Comment: Ok so the problem seems to come from your schema definition. What you could try is to define your ```transactions``` field as "[TransactionSchema]". If it doesn't work try to do the following : https://pastebin.com/ZjXi9nxw

Answer (score 0):

```
var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
   time: {
       type: String
  },
  date : {
    type: String
  },
  transactionType : {
    type: String
  },
  email : {
    type: String
  },
  amount: {
    type: String
  },
  txHash:{
    type: String
  }
})

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  ethAddress: {
    type: String
  },
  privateKey: {
    type: String
  },
  transactions: [
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TransactionModel' // this should be the name of your 
    // transactions model
    }
  ]
})
```

then you query should be

```
User.findOne({ _id: userId })
.populate('transactions')   
.then(user => {
  console.log(user)
})
.catch(e => {
  consoel.log('error')
});
```

please i used promise because i found it easier, you could convert it to your callback function

I hope this helps